# How to pause on WindowClosing | JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

What i'm trying to do is, when the app is closing using X button from title bar, change the Label to "Closing", pause for 1500ms then close.

**Code**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class app {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Timer timer = new Timer(1500, new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        JDialog dialog = new JDialog(new JFrame(), "", true);
        dialog.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        JLabel label = new JLabel();
        label.setText("Running");
        dialog.add(label);
        dialog.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent event) {
                label.setText("Closing");
                timer.start();
            }
        });
        dialog.pack();
        dialog.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

The probem is it won't even pause

**I've tried**

using `Thread.sleep()`. The label won't change on sleep

```
dialog.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent event) {
        label.setText("Closing");
        Thread.sleep(1500);
        System.exit(0);
    }
});
```

Comment: Why do you want to wait 1.5 seconds to close the JFrame?  Use a [Swing Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) to update the JLabel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you use the 'exit' process in a timer, specify the default close operation not to closing the form.

```
dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
```